# Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters

Tags: truffle, ganache

Following my first tutorial on truffle, zeppelin and ganache (and nothing else).

I am trying truffle migrate. The code compiles, then issues this error:

```
> Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network at http://127.0.0.1:7545. Check your network configuration.

Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > 5777
```

truffle-config.js is:

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
```

and

ganache-cli is `Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545`

If I am not mistaken it should be trying to connect to port 8545. How can I fix ths?

I have read other questions and tried `truffle migrate --reset` and receive a similar error.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to edit your truffle-config.js to match data from your error message? Changing the from 8545 to 7545 just in case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed ganache. Try installing it in the system.

Command:

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```